# selectInput in R shiny

Tags: mysql, r, user-interface, shiny

I want to select from a list read in from a Mysql query. I am getting an error in the code. I must be doing something just completely wrong, but not sure what.

I would like to select from a list of skus read in from a sql query. I get an error in the ui portion.

I am not even sure if this is possible, but to list out all skus would be extremely timely.

I am getting the following errors:

Error in tag("div", list(...)) : 
  argument "sidebarPanel" is missing, with no default

> shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
>   Error in force(ui) : object 'ui' not found

```
library('RMySQL')
library('plyr')
library('shiny')
library('scales')
library(shinyapps)
library(ggplot2)



con <- dbConnect(MySQL(), user="user", password="password",dbname="DB", host="host");


rank<-dbGetQuery(con,"select sku from DB")




#build a shiny app to select which sku to pick
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    hist(rnorm(input$obs), col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
  })
}

ui <- pageWithSidebar(
  ## Application title

    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("obs", "Number of observations:", min = 10, max = 500, value = 100),
      selectInput(
        'e0', '0. An ordinary select input', choices = unique(rank$sku),
        selectize = FALSE
      ),

      mainPanel(plotOutput("distPlot"))

  )

)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: What error are you getting? (Could you also post the result of `traceback()` after you get the error?

Comment: Error in tag("div", list(...)) : 
  argument "sidebarPanel" is missing, with no default
> 
> shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
Error in force(ui) : object 'ui' not found

Comment: `pageWithSidebar` requires a headerPanel as the first argument. Add `headerPanel("Some Title"),` before the `sidebarPanel(` line.

Answer (score 2):

You have both a **missing bracket** near your `selectize = FALSE` and (as  @DavidRobinson has suggested) you need a **headerPanel**.

**CODE FIX**

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
# con <- dbConnect(MySQL(), user="user", password="password",dbname="DB", host="host");
# rank<-dbGetQuery(con,"select sku from DB")
# for test hard coding the rank as I dont have your data
# test rank
rank$sku <- c(1,2,3)

#build a shiny app to select which sku to pick
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    hist(rnorm(input$obs), col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
  })
}

ui <- pageWithSidebar(
  ## Application title

  # missing headerPanel
  headerPanel(title = "Hello"),

  # missing bracket after selectize
  sidebarPanel(
    sliderInput("obs", "Number of observations:", min = 10, max = 500, value = 100),
    selectInput(
      'e0', '0. An ordinary select input', choices = unique(rank$sku),
      selectize = FALSE) 
    ),

  mainPanel(plotOutput("distPlot"))    
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**RESULT**

[image: FixedSidebarShinyWebpageImage]

**ANOTHER SHINY PAGE UI OPTION**

You can can also use a tabbed page structure, replacing `ui` above with this code (note it does not require headerPanel like above):

```
# navbar tabbed page example - without headerPanel
ui2 <- navbarPage(title = "Hello Another Style", 
           tabPanel("Chart Panel",
                    sidebarLayout(
                      sidebarPanel(
                        sliderInput("obs", "Number of observations:", 
                                    min = 10, max = 500, value = 100),
                        selectInput(
                          'e0', '0. An ordinary select input', 
                          choices = unique(rank$sku),
                          selectize = FALSE)
                        ),
                      mainPanel(
                        plotOutput("distPlot")
                      )
                    )
           ),
           tabPanel("Instructions",
                    mainPanel(
                       p("Notes here for example...")
                    )
           )        

)
```

**SECOND RESULT**

[image: Shiny-NavPanelExamplePage1]

And then on second panel...

[image: Shiny-NavPanelExamplePage2]

**DEBUGGING ADVICE**

These `Shiny` pages can have lots of brackets, so **pace over your code selecting brackets in turn carefully in your editor** like RStudio to make sure your brackets match okay.

All the best!

Comment: @megv, also update your RStudio! The 0.99 strand is improving the editor with autocompletes so you wont suffer this again - [release notes](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/release-notes/) "For Shiny applications, autocompletions for ui.R + server.R pairs".